# Change color With Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this object taken from an API, i want to change the color when status change i tried to do this :

```html
<b-badge :variant="variant">{{ $t(contract.status) }}</b-badge>
```

script:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["getTeammates", "isCompleted"]),
  variant () {
    if (status == "pending") {
      return "warning";
    } else if (status == "confirmed") {
      return "success";
    } else if (status == "waiting_for_approval"){
      return "danger";
    } else {
      return "dark";
    }
  },
},
```

I don't know why it doesn't work,
the color is always dark.

Comment: I need more code to help you :)

Comment: is very difficult to post all code here, you have slack?

Answer (score 0):

`status` is not defined in the computed method `variant`.

Based on your code I guess it should be `this.contract.status`

```js
variant () {
  if (this.contract.status == "pending") {
    return "warning";
  } else if (this.contract.status == "confirmed") {
    return "success";
  } else if (this.contract.status == "waiting_for_approval"){
    return "danger";
  } else {
    return "dark";
  }
},
```

Bonus: If you want an advice, I would suggest to replace all those `if` with a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: I put this.contract.status  but in console return this error :      [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

Comment: please post the hole component code